# nginx rewrite phpphumb & cache-control

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to use phpthumb generator & add some custom expires header to all images

When I use only phpthumb rewrites it working but when add cache-control rewrites can't generate new thumbs

my code is:

```
#thumb generation
location /cache/ {
   if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
   }
   rewrite ^/cache/(.*)$ /cache/index.php?thumb=$1 permanent;
}
```

and for cache-control:

```
location ~* .(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
  expires 7d;
  access_log off;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

I try also this with no luck ..

```
#for phpthumb
location /cache/ {
   try_files $uri @missing;
}

location @missing {
  rewrite ^/cache/(.*)$ /cache/index.php?thumb=$1 permanent;
}

location ~* .(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
 expires 7d;
 access_log off;
 add_header Pragma public;
 add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks,
T.

Comment: A request can only match one `location`. Not two.

Comment: I'm OK the first time when thumb is created to not add cache headers. but I can't create thumb.

Answer (score 0):

After a night on it, I found a right way :)

```
location ~* \.(?:jpe?g|png)$ {
  expires 7d;
  access_log off;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";

  try_files $uri $uri/ @thumbs;
}

location @thumbs {  
  rewrite ^/cache/(.*)$ /cache/index.php?thumb=$1 permanent;
}
```

My big problem that produces incorrect rewrites was on nginx.conf:

```
# cache informations about FDs, frequently accessed files
# can boost performance, but you need to test those values
#open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
#open_file_cache_valid 30s;
#open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
#open_file_cache_errors on;
```

After I comment those lines rewrites work correctly.